# Como encontrar posição da ocorrência de uma String em um arquivo em JAVA?

Tags: java, arquivo

Estou tendo que implementar um trabalho para a faculdade, onde eu preciso ler um arquivo de texto, palavra por palavra, salvá-las numa tabela hash e então, de acordo com outras palavras lidas num segundo arquivo, informar a ocorrência de cada uma delas. Até aí tudo bem!

O problema é que também preciso armazenar a posição de início de cada ocorrência e eu não sei como ler palavra por palavra do arquivo de modo que eu consiga salvar isso. A única forma que eu consigo pensar em fazer isso é usando o *RandomAccessFile*, mas como eu faria para ler palavra por palavra?

Atualmente estou lendo as palavras da seguinte maneira:

```
String palavra;
File arq = new File("teste.txt");
try{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(arq);
    while(in.hasNext()){
        palavra = in.next().toLowerCase();
    }
}catch(IOException e){
}
```

Ignorei o resto do código, pois o que realmente interessa é a leitura das palavras.

Comment: Você quer buscar em um texto algumas palavras especificas da sua lista e gravar a posição inicial e final desta palavra encontrada?

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt eu estou salvando as palavras do meu texto em uma tabela hash. Eu preciso salvar além da palavra em si, a posição inicial dela no arquivo. Depois eu farei uma pesquisa por algumas palavras e aí vou exibir se essas palavras estão no arquivo, com que frequência aparecem e a posição inicial de cada uma das ocorrências.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi completamente o que você quer, mas segue um exemplo:

Primeiramente você vai precisar pegar todo o conteúdo do texto, para isso crie o seguinte método na classe main:

```
private static String getTexto(String nomeArquivo) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder conteudo = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nomeArquivo));
    while (reader.ready()) {
        String linha = reader.readLine();
        conteudo.append(linha);
    }
    reader.close();

    return conteudo.toString();
}
```

Depois crie o método que vai retornar um LinkedHashMap contendo as palavras existentes do texto e sua posição inicial no texto:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> getPalavrasDoTexto(String conteudoTexto) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Integer> listaDePalavrasDoTexto = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String palavra = "";
    int posicaoInicioBusca = 0;
    for (Character caracter : conteudoTexto.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(caracter)) { // verificação para armazenar somente letras
            palavra += caracter;
        } else {
            if (!palavra.isEmpty() && !listaDePalavrasDoTexto.containsKey(palavra.toLowerCase())) { // verificação para não pegar a palavra novamente caso já tenha encontrado antes
                int posicaoDeInicio = conteudoTexto.indexOf(palavra, posicaoInicioBusca); // aqui pegamos a posição da palavra a partir da posicao da ultima palavra
                posicaoInicioBusca = posicaoDeInicio;

                listaDePalavrasDoTexto.put(palavra.toLowerCase(), posicaoDeInicio);
            }

            palavra = "";
        }
    }

    return listaDePalavrasDoTexto;
}
```

Crie também o método que retorna as palavras de busca, segue:

```
private static List<String> getPalavrasParaBuscar(String nomeArquivo) throws IOException {
    List<String> listaDePalavrasBusca = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nomeArquivo));
    while (reader.ready()) {
        String palavra = reader.readLine();
        listaDePalavrasBusca.add(palavra.toLowerCase());
    }
    reader.close();

    return listaDePalavrasBusca;
}
```

Crie um arquivo chamado `texto.txt` contendo todo o texto e outro chamado `palavras.txt` com uma palavra por linha, ambos no diretório raiz.

Dentro do método main, coloque o seguinte:

```
String texto = getTexto("texto.txt");
List<String> palavrasParaBuscar = getPalavrasParaBuscar("palavras.txt");
Map<String, Integer> palavrasDoTexto = getPalavrasDoTexto(texto);

for (String palavraParaBuscar : palavrasParaBuscar) {
    if (palavrasDoTexto.containsKey(palavraParaBuscar)) { // só vamos buscar as palavras que já foram encontradas anteriormente

        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println("BUSCANDO PALAVRA: " + palavraParaBuscar + ", POS INICIO TEXTO: "+ palavrasDoTexto.get(palavraParaBuscar));

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(palavraParaBuscar, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

        while (matcher.find()) { // enquanto acharmos alguma ocorrência
            String palavraEncontrada = matcher.group();
            int posicaoDeInicio = matcher.start();
            int posicaoFinal = matcher.end();

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("PALAVRA ENCONTRADA: " + palavraEncontrada);
            System.out.println("POS INICIO: " + posicaoDeInicio);
            System.out.println("POS FINAL: " + posicaoFinal);
        }
    }
}
```